# MongoOperations "id" selector returning null

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am using the MongoOperations interface in the Spring-data-mongodb 1.1.1.RELEASE and any query using "id" as selector returns null: `Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is("5X")))`

However, when I used the Mongo class withing the Java driver and run the query it works as expected. i.e.: `dbCollection.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is("5X")).getQueryObject()));`

Based on my research, this should work for the MongoOperations interface, and the selector "id" should not clash with the "_id" selector. Has anyone run in to this issue, or anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Check your second code-line. It lacks a quote after `id`

Comment: @user2116627 Do you have `id` and `_id` fields in the same document?

Comment: I am still searching answer for this :(

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that there is no `id`, but there is `_id` - try that. In mongodb, PK default field has "_id" name.

If you need to find documents only by id, why don't you use something like `findById(id)` in mongoTemplate if you use Spring or do something like that:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(getCollectionName());
DBObject searchById = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(idString));
DBObject found = coll.findOne(searchById);
```

In spring mongo try:

```
YourObject obj= mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("id").is("5X")),  YourObject.class, "yourCollectionName");
```

Comment: Author wrote: `and the selector "id" should not clash with the "_id" selector`

Comment: Well, then how is he gonna get the value of field "id" that doesn't exist?

Comment: The "id" field does exist, that is why the query works as expected when using the Java Mongodb driver. The problem is that the MongoTemplate is not returning the correct results. So to clarify there is the normal PK "_id" field and there is a "id" field in my document.

Comment: Please provide solution when "id" and "_id" both exist. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like fields named "id" that aren't Document Id's. Use the @Field("id") annotation to map it in the class.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
...
@Field("id") 
public int id;
```